# Illegal space in \url{} using xurl

Tags: spacing, italic, letterspacing, xurl

I have a problem with the `\url{}` using `\usepackage{xurl}`. I'm using LuaLaTeX.
In the case I set the font to italic there are illegal spaces after "f" and "V" sometimes. When it's upright there is no problem.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,                        
fontsize=12pt,                        
]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=semi}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "wxyz",
    type = "alternate",
    data = {
      ["one.osf"] = "one.01",
      ["one.tosf"] = "one.tosf01",
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[Numbers={OldStyle,,Proportional},RawFeature=+wxyz]

\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{italics} 
  { encoding = *, shape = it* }          
\SetTracking                             
  { encoding = *, shape = it* }          
  {}

  \DeclareMicrotypeSet*{smallcapsi}
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2},
     shape    = {sc*,si,scit}
   }

\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\itshape}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Referentenentwurf des \textit{Bundesministeriums der Finanzen}, Entwurf eines Gesetzes zur Umsetzung der Protokollerklärung zum Gesetz zur Anpassung der Abgabenordnung an den Zollkodex der Union und zur Änderung weiterer steuerlicher \textit{Vorschriften} vom 19.2.2015, \url{https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Gesetzestexte/Gesetze_Gesetzesvorhaben/Abteilungen/Abteilung_IV/18_Legislaturperiode/Gesetze_Verordnungen/2015-11-05-Steueraenderungsgesetz-2015/1-Referentenentwurf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3}.

\bigskip
Bundesministerium der Finanzen, Entwurf eines aktualisierten BMF-Schrei"-bens zur Anwendung des Umwandlungssteuergesetzes (UmwStE) vom 6.12.2023, \url{https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Downloads/BMF_Schreiben/Steuerarten/Koerperschaftsteuer_Umwandlungsteuer/2023-10-11-entwurf-umwStE.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you should specify which engine you are using. I tried with lualatex, and I can see the problem and it persists if you remove the `microtype` code.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: I believe that `\itshape` adds a little space after the final letter, so that it does not lean into the following upright text. There are other ways to invoke Italics, so try one of tho0se.

Comment: When I try ```\textit{\url{https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Gesetzestexte/Gesetze_Gesetzesvorhaben/Abteilungen/Abteilung_IV/18_Legislaturperiode/Gesetze_Verordnungen/2015-11-05-Steueraenderungsgesetz-2015/1-Referentenentwurf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3}}``` it's still the same. Can you suggest some of the other ways, please?